# Javascript update multiple form totals from checked boxes

Tags: javascript

I have a form with various items with checkboxes and those items may be repeated multiple times. I'd like to have another table or form that shows all those items and has a running total for the number of items that are checked and it updates as they are checked.

Let's say I've got the initial form like this:

```
<form name="myform">
<input type="checkbox" name="model1" value="2">2 x model1
<input type="checkbox" name="model2" value="2">2 x model2
<input type="checkbox" name="model3" value="2">2 x model3
<input type="checkbox" name="model1" value="1">1 x model1
<input type="checkbox" name="model1" value="4">4 x model1
<input type="checkbox" name="model3" value="5">5 x model3
<p>
Totals: <br>
<input type="text" name="totalmodel1" value="0" size="2"><br>
<input type="text" name="totalmodel2" value="0" size="2"><br>
<input type="text" name="totalmodel3" value="0" size="2"><br>
</form>
```

How can I get the totals to update as the items are checked off. I've used javascript to update lots of other stuff like this and I've found examples that will add up my choices if they are all to be added together, but I haven't been able to successfully make it work with adding multiple items separately.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: If you could supply a [jsfiddle](jsfiddle.net) with that you got at the moment, I think that would make it easier to see what you’re after.

Comment: I think part of my problem was that jsfiddle didn't work for me. Maybe I set something wrong on jsfiddle.net, but even after figuring it out and trying stuff that worked on my website, it wouldn't work on jsfiddle. I'll post my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I made a JS Fiddle as an example of where to start... [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/yeqbjxLz/2/)

Basically what I did was:

- Relate the input text to checkboxes:

  ```
  var modelNum = ($(this).attr("name")).slice(($(this).attr("name").length) - 1, $(this).attr("name").length);

  var child = "totalmodel" + modelNum;
  ```
- Make input text only appear if related checkbox is checked:

  ```
  if (this.checked) {
       $("input").each(function() {
           if ($(this).attr("name") == child) {
                $(this).show();
           }
       });
  } else {
       $("input").each(function() {
           if ($(this).attr("name") == child) {
               $(this).hide();
           }
       });
  }
  ```
- And show you how to get the value of text (assuming user will enter integer):

  ```
  $("input").each(function(){ //This is how you get the value of each...
      if($(this).is(":text")){
          var value = $(this).attr("value");
      }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

So I had previously found an example at http://www.madirish.net/11 that did what I wanted but it was only for one item to total up. I needed to total multiple items separately. I had been trying to modify his code to my needs and it wasn't working, but then I realized his code wouldn't work when I pasted it into jsfiddle. So I tried it on my own server and it worked. I gave up on jsfiddle (I'm sure it's my fault somehow that it didn't work) and began testing on my own server. Here's an example output of what I did to get it to work (please ignore the ugly layout...I didn't need it to be pretty while testing).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkTotal1() {
        document.listForm.total1.value = '';
        var sum = 0;
        if (document.getElementsByName("choice1").length == 1) {
            if (document.listForm.choice1.checked) {
                sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice1.value);
            }
        } else {
            for (i=0;i<document.listForm.choice1.length;i++) {
                if (document.listForm.choice1[i].checked) {
                    sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice1[i].value);
                }
            }
        }
        document.listForm.total1.value = sum;
    }
    function checkTotal2() {
        document.listForm.total2.value = '';
        var sum = 0;
        if (document.getElementsByName("choice2").length == 1) {
            if (document.listForm.choice2.checked) {
                sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice2.value);
            }
        } else {
            for (i=0;i<document.listForm.choice2.length;i++) {
                if (document.listForm.choice2[i].checked) {
                    sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice2[i].value);
                }
            }
        }
        document.listForm.total2.value = sum;
    }
    function checkTotal3() {
        document.listForm.total3.value = '';
        var sum = 0;
        if (document.getElementsByName("choice3").length == 1) {
            if (document.listForm.choice3.checked) {
                sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice3.value);
            }
        } else {
            for (i=0;i<document.listForm.choice3.length;i++) {
                if (document.listForm.choice3[i].checked) {
                    sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice3[i].value);
                }
            }
        }
        document.listForm.total3.value = sum;
    }
    function checkTotal4() {
        document.listForm.total4.value = '';
        var sum = 0;
        if (document.getElementsByName("choice4").length == 1) {
            if (document.listForm.choice4.checked) {
                sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice4.value);
            }
        } else {
            for (i=0;i<document.listForm.choice4.length;i++) {
                if (document.listForm.choice4[i].checked) {
                    sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice4[i].value);
                }
            }
        }
        document.listForm.total4.value = sum;
    }
    function checkTotal5() {
        document.listForm.total5.value = '';
        var sum = 0;
        if (document.getElementsByName("choice5").length == 1) {
            if (document.listForm.choice5.checked) {
                sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice5.value);
            }
        } else {
            for (i=0;i<document.listForm.choice5.length;i++) {
                if (document.listForm.choice5[i].checked) {
                    sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice5[i].value);
                }
            }
        }
        document.listForm.total5.value = sum;
    }
</script>

<form name="listForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top">
                <input type="checkbox" name="choice1" value="1" onchange="checkTotal1()">1 x mod1<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="choice1" value="1" onchange="checkTotal1()">1 x mod1<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="choice2" value="2" onchange="checkTotal2()">2 x mod2<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="choice2" value="2" onchange="checkTotal2()">2 x mod2<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="choice3" value="1" onchange="checkTotal3()">1 x mod3<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="choice3" value="1" onchange="checkTotal3()">1 x mod3<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="choice3" value="1" onchange="checkTotal3()">1 x mod3<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="choice4" value="1" onchange="checkTotal4()">1 x mod4<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="choice5" value="1" onchange="checkTotal5()">1 x mod5<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="choice5" value="1" onchange="checkTotal5()">1 x mod5<br>
            </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product Model</th>
                    <th>Qty Received</th>
                    <th>Qty Checked</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>mod1</td>
                    <td align="right">2</td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="3" name="total1" value="0"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>mod2</td>
                    <td align="right">4</td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="3" name="total2" value="0"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>mod3</td>
                    <td align="right">3</td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="3" name="total3" value="0"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>mod4</td>
                    <td align="right">1</td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="3" name="total4" value="0"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>mod5</td>
                    <td align="right">2</td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="3" name="total5" value="0"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```